# jQuery, Hiding Paragraphs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a random html page with internal jQuery, I'm trying to get jQuery to hide two of three paragraphs, and to do this for 5 seconds, but when I load the html file, all paragraphs are immediately visible. Can anyone help?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            var $ = jQuery;
            $("p").each(function (idx) {
                if(idx >= 1) {
                    $(this).hide(500);
                }
            });
        </script>
        <p>This is the first paragraph</p>
        <p>This is the second paragraph</p>
        <p>This is the third paragraph</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to wrap your code with `$()` because the elements aren't loaded yet.

```
$(function(){
    $("p:not(:first-child)").hide(5000);
});
```

<kbd>[TRY-A-DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/cT3mC/)</kbd>

Also I believe `500` is a typo since `5000` is 5 seconds.

As [@David Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15605352/jquery-hiding-paragraphs/#comment22131438_15605378) suggested, you can further simplify it into:

```
$(function(){
    $("p:gt(0)").hide(5000);  //:gt means "greater than..."
});
```

Comment: While that selector works, why not simplify further: `$('p:gt(0)').hide();`, or `$('p').slice(1).hide()`? Though +1 for an appropriate selector *and* the timing correction. And, of course, native CSS selectors: `$('p + p')` and `$('p ~ p')`, which allow for the selector to be passed to the native `document.querySelectorAll()` (in browsers in which it's available).

Comment: @DavidThomas - In my opinion this is easier to understand than `:gt`.

Comment: I appreciate that, but that's true only until one learns what `:gt()` does. Still, your answer's right; and it really is just a matter of preference.

Comment: +1 for answer, and +1 for David, i didn't know about `:gt()`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to wait DOM ready event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // your code
});
```